# Making a simple app launcher with urxvt and fzf

Tags: bash, rxvt, fzf

I've been trying to cobble together a simple program launcher with a terminal and fzf to bind to a hotkey but I haven't been able to make the terminal window close once the program starts without terminating the child process too. I'm a beginner with the shell so it's likely I'm missing a crucial step.

What I've tried so far:

```
urxvtc -name menu -e bash -c 'compgen -c | sort -u | fzf | sh
```

It's named menu so it can spawn under a special rule and I had to do -e bash because my shell (zsh) wouldn't recognise compgen.

A person on discord suggested:

```
urxvt -name menu -e bash -c 'cmd=$(compgen -c | sort -u | fzf); setsid $cmd'
```

This did detach the window from the program it launched, however I couldn't find a way to make the terminal window autoclose when fzf evaluates and outputs to stdout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is precisely what you're looking for, but adding the fork argument to setsid (-f) seems to work great for non-terminal commands:

```
urxvt -name menu -e bash -c 'cmd=$(compgen -c | sort -u | fzf); setsid -f $cmd'
```